# High precision timing for High-Def mouse events

Tags: c#, windows, mouseevent, stopwatch, raw-input

I'm working with a high definition mouse (logitech g500) in Windows, for which I would like to obtain a low-latency timestamp on raw mouse events. I'm using the timestamps to compute "pauses" between mouse-movements, so it's the relative precision of the timestamps that matter .

I'm using the RAW INPUT API to monitor mouse events. There is no timing information contained in the messages so I used the Stopwatch in Windows. Diagnostics to obtain a "timestamp" when event handlers are triggered -- i.e. the first action in the mouse event handler is to read the stopwatch for ticks elapsed.

Since I don't have any ground truth to work with in this case, does any one see immediate and obvious pitfalls with this approach? Or better, if you've worked with Stopwatch before any comments on the latency and its variability over different reads of the stopwatch?

Comment: You'll run the serious risk of only really measuring how responsive your UI thread is to the WM_INPUT message.  Which is correlated to what your thread did previously, before it re-entered the message loop.  And highly variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `Stopwatch` class uses the high performance timer on your CPU if available, so it's the highest resolution timer you're going to get.

You can check to make sure you have a high precision instance by using the `IsHighPrecision` property.